# Missing ) after argument list, don't see a reason why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason I'm getting missing `)` after argument list on line 2 (javascript), but don't see the reason why this happens...

I've been trying using some scape "\" and sending just 1 parameter but nothing works

```
$.each(enlaces, function (i) {
  var init = false;
  lista.append('<li class="list-group-item"><span onclick="load(' + init + ',' + enlaces[i] + ')"> ' + enlaces[i] + '</span></li>');
});
```

I need to figure this out since it is stopping me to move on

Comment: side note; http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/  the arguments passed to the each callback are `index, element`, so you don't need to do `enlaces[i]`.  Just use the element passed in.

Comment: Other than that, you need to see what the values of `enlaces` are, and see if they will cause the html that is being passed to `append()` to be invalid

Comment: And `init` should probably be a string, rather than a boolean, because you are appending it to the string.

Comment: What is `enlaces[i]`? If it's a string like `foo bar baz` then your onclick attribute will be `load(false,foo bar baz)` which is not valid JavaScript. In truth you should be binding events with `on` or `addEventListener` or some other method that doesn't require dynamically generating JavaScript.

Comment: I presume you mean when you click on the `<li>`, not just running this code. Well, you're composing JavaScript dynamically with plain string concatenation and `enlaces[i]` can possibly contain anything.

Comment: I'd also try using a template string to make that more manageable. Try: `<li class="list-group-item"><span onclick="load( ${init} , ${enlaces[i]} )">${enlaces[i]}</span></li>`

Comment: Template literals are not going to solve invalid html construction.  Just makes it easier to do so

Comment: You must have an issue in your variable content somewhere. The barebones of what you have is correct; eg: https://jsfiddle.net/zfc0jhd1/

Comment: enlaces[i] is a string

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've provided.  Even if `enlaces[0] = '('` it wouldn't give that error.  It's more likely the line just before or a few lines before the code you've provided (in your original code) that you've not provided a closing `)` for.   Try creating an [mcve] that **demonstrates** the problem.

Comment: From vote options: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to *reproduce* it in the question itself**.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid making invalid html, bind logically instead.

```
$.each(enlaces, function (index, enlace) {
  var $item = $(`<li class="list-group-item"><span>${enlace}</span></li>`);

  $item.find('span').on('click', function(){ load( false, enlace ); });
  lista.append($item);
});
```